# Why does my PHP tag does not work even though i (think i) did everything right?

Tags: php, html

I have a php file (converted from html) with a php tag inside that does not work, for some reason...

Here is part of my code, thanks a lot for your help...

```
<footer class="w3-container w3-blue w3-center w3-margin-top">
  <p>Find me on social media.</p>
  <a href="https://facebook.com/maximilien.ollier">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i><a/>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mxollier/">
  <i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity"></i><a/>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/Maxollier">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"></i><a/>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/maximilien-ollier-526094154/">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity"></i><a/>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Heroic_watermelon">
    <i class="fa fa-reddit w3-hover-opacity"></i><a/>
    <i class="fa fa-wechat w3-hover-opacity"></i><a/>
  <a> Copyright &copy; 
    <?php echo date("Y")." "; ?> 
<?php bloginfo('name')." "; ?>. All Rights Reserved.</a>
</footer>
```

[image: what the website looks like]

Comment: what does the HTML source code tell? does the year being echoed?

Comment: I just want the copyright section on the bottom to show an updated copyright corresponding the the year we are in

Comment: I should let you know that i am quite new at this haha

Comment: Right-click in browser, view Page Source. Wait. Did you host your webpage in a PHP-enabled web server?

Comment: Isn't there a way to preview your php code without doing that?

Comment: use a PHP development server in your localhost. Which OS are you using?

Comment: My website isn't online yet, this is just an assignment, i will not put it online

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: Easiest way: In the Command Prompt, navigate to the folder your files are in. Then issue this command: `php -S localhost:12345`. This command will run a development server with URL: `http://localhost:12345`. Browse this website

Comment: This assumed you installed PHP locally. Alternatively, you can use XAMPP, MAMP or something equivalent.